# Solventar este error "PHP CS Fixer: executablePath not found, please check your settings. It will set to built-in php-cs-fixer.phar. Try again!"

Tags: php, vscode, extensiones

Me acabo de registrar en este foro, llevo mucho tiempo consultándolo, pero no había participado hasta ahora.

Estoy utilizando VSCode para programar en PHP (siempre había usado EditPadPro) y me encuentro que, al intentar formatear el código, con las opciones por defecto no lo hace como yo quiero, entonces, he mirado y rebuscado por todas partes y lo que más se recomienda es Prettier, pero este no tiene casi ninguna opción de personalizar el tipo de formateo que se desea.

La otra opción que he encontrado, y que parece que sí tiene esa opción, es PHP CS Fixer, lo he revisado, configurado y demás, pero me da un error al que no consigo encontrarle solución, es este:

> PHP CS Fixer: executablePath not found, please check your settings. It will set to built-in php-cs-fixer.phar. Try again!

Por otra parte, lo que yo pretendo, principalmente, es que las llaves "{" de apertura, queden en la misma línea que la declaración de la clase, método, bucle o donde sea que estén, algo tal que así:

```
class nombreClase extends nombreClasePadre {
      protected $propiedad = false;

      public function metodo() {

            foreach ($this->propiedad as $prop) {
```

Y sin la opción de usar la extensión, con la opción por defecto o con Prettier, queda tal que así:

```
    class nombreClase extends nombreClasePadre
    {
      protected $propiedad = false;

      public function metodo()
      {

            foreach ($this->propiedad as $prop)
            {
```

Básicamente es que no consigo que se formatee correctamente de manera sencilla, sin tener que ir línea por línea haciendo este trabajo que es muy tedioso y poco productivo.

Agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda al respecto, me sirve tanto solución para el problema de esta extensión como la sugerencia de otra extensión que haga lo que necesito.

Answer (score 0):

Para el problema del PHP CS Fixer he buscado un poco i tiene que ver con el **Path relativo**, por lo que he visto podria funcionar desde consola o reinstalandolo.

Comando para la consola:

```
php-cs-fixer
```

Link del foro mencionado (está en inglés):

https://github.com/junstyle/vscode-php-cs-fixer/issues/46

Por otro lado, pues usar PHPFormater como alternativa a PHP CS Fixer.

Link del PHPFORMATER:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Sophisticode.php-formatter

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, he probado a reinstalar PHP CS Fixer, pero sigo obteniendo el mismo resultado.

En cuanto a PHPFormater, en su página hay una indicación de que está en desuso:

Esta extensión está en desuso porque ya no se mantiene.

Por lo que no me fio mucho de usarla, ya que, es muy posible que aparezcan errores por la falta de mantenimiento.

A ver si a alguien se le ocurre qué se podría hacer.